# How can I integrate speech recognition on Unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech-recognition

I am doing some research and I cannot find any examples where Unity integrates speech recognition as input layer.

Do anyone knows an example of it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for me.. I use. Net 3.0 speech recognition to make it happen..i use visual studio c# to make the speech recognition system and then i integrate it with unity at runtime..u need a code in unity to invoke the speech recognition exe and the code need to be able to fetch data from the exe (.readline)..u need to use system.threading here in order to avoid unity to halt when speech recognition exe is invoke..

Hope this help..

Comment: Please provide a brief example or a link to an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some many use [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/4518) from asset store. If you want to dig more deeper then there is several different ways for several different platrform. Probably [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/587899/implement-voice-recognition-in-unity.html) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Windows System from 8.1 to 10 exists a Lybrary to do the work for you.
PhraseRecognitionSystem
class in UnityEngine.Windows.Speech

You have the official Unity Documentation here:

[Unity Documentation PhraseRecognitionSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.PhraseRecognitionSystem.html)

Comment: this is only supported in windows 10 not 8.1.